# WFFM 8.2 Trying to manually insert form onto razor view

Tags: xdb, wffm

In the header html of our website we would like to insert a form, but it is not accessible from experience editor or content editor so I would like to insert it directly into the cshtml page for the header. I feel like it should be relatively simple, but have run into the wall.

I tried the below (but I really don't know what I'm doing) and it did not work.

```
@Html.Sitecore().Rendering("/sitecore/layout/Renderings/Modules/Web Forms for Marketers/Mvc Form", new {"formId","{11223344-5566-7788-9900-AABBCCDDEEFF}"})
```

I also tried:

```
@Html.Sitecore().RenderingItem("{11223344-5566-7788-9900-AABBCCDDEEFF}")
```

And I tried substituting the path for the id of the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing FormId try to pass Data Source for the MVC form, like:

```
@Html.Sitecore().Rendering("{F2CCA16D-7524-4E99-8EE0-78FF6394A3B3}", new { DataSource = "{11223344-5566-7788-9900-AABBCCDDEEFF}" })
```

Where {F2CCA16D-7524-4E99-8EE0-78FF6394A3B3} is the WFFM MVC Form and {11223344-5566-7788-9900-AABBCCDDEEFF} is the WFFM form as a data source.

**Update:**

You will need to pass Unique Id of the form as below:

```
@Html.Sitecore().Rendering("{F2CCA16D-7524-4E99-8EE0-78FF6394A3B3}", new { Datasource = "<id of the form item>" , UniqueId = "<unique id of the form rendering>"})
```

reference: https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/web-forms-for-marketers/en/insert-a-web-form-directly-on-a-web-page.html

Comment: That generated a LOT of error messages. The root cause seemed to be this error: ...Message: uniqueId is empty
Parameter name: uniqueId
Source: Sitecore.Kernel
   at Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.ArgumentCondition(Boolean condition, String argumentName, String message)
   at Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.Models.FormModel..ctor(Guid uniqueId)
   at Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.Models.FormModel..ctor(Guid uniqueId, Item item)...

Comment: @Michael, check the update section in the answer.

Comment: Thank you @Mohammed Syam. How do I find that id in my instance?

Comment: I believe it should be the wffm form Id.

Comment: I'm glad it worked.

Comment: Looks like randomly creating an id works fine to get the form to display. I don't know what the potential side effects could be but I'll do some tests. I think this sufficiently answers my question, so I am marking it as the answer, thank you.